# Openjpa generate entities from table skips one column

Tags: orm, code-generation, openjpa, rad

I have a table with following schema (for keeping logs):

```
* BIGINT ID
* TIMESTAMP TIME
VARCHAR(255) NULLABLE COMMENT
VARCHAR(255) DESCRIPTION
INTEGER NULLABLE AFFECTED_OBJECT_ID
```

When I generate entity for table it results in :

```
@EmbeddedId
private HistoryPK id;

private String comment;
private String description;
...
getters/setters
...
```

I use RAD  8.5.5.1, that built on top of Eclipse Platform 3.6.3. Database is DB2 9.1.

Somehow AFFECTED_OBJECT_ID is not translated to the entity. What can fix it? (I know that I can fix this manually in code, but I really want to trust my IDE) Or may be I'm doing something wrong?

I tried disconnecting and connecting again to database, no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning project did fixed it.